# What is wrong with resources loader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, headjs

My page contains the code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/javascript/head.load.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        head.load([ '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/javascript/timecookie.js',
                    'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' ],
                function() {
                    console.log("Done loading resources");
                });
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- this fuction does not work -->
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            console.log("running");
            var url='myapp.com/mainpage.jsp?check='+this.id;
            alert(url);
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

I faset that jquery (it has been loaded) does not work arter such loading. Whats wrong with resouces loader?

Comment: are you getting any errors in the developer tools console ... been scratching my head ... what is "faset"?

Comment: you need to move your jquery code i.e. `$(document).ready...` below the `console.log("Done loading resources");` i.e. success handler of `head` if you go with `head.js` way...

Comment: @JaromandaX there is an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ ` on line `$(document).ready(function(){ `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try  with below approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        head.load([ '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/javascript/timecookie.js',
                    'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' ],
                function() {
                    console.log("Done loading resources");

                    $(document).ready(function(){ 
                         $('button').click(function(){
                             console.log("running");
                             var url='myapp.com/mainpage.jsp?check='+this.id;
                             alert(url);
                         });
                    });    

                });
    </script>
```